# Return number of rows affected with multiple queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing some dynamic SQL in SQL Server. There are a few queries combined into one. The first query selects data, the second deletes, the third inserts, and the last deletes a temp table:

```
SET @completeSQL = @tempProdSQL + @deleteSQL + @insertSQL + ' DROP TABLE #tempProd'

PRINT(@completeSQL)

EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @completeSQL

SET @archiveSize = @@ROWCOUNT
```

I know that I can use `@@Rowcount`, but I'm getting a value of 0. I believe this is because the last command is to drop the table.

Is there a way to get the rows affected after the `@tempProdSQL` command? I would prefer to not separate the execution if it will impact performance.

Comment: `@@rowcount` only returns the rows impacted from the previously executed statement. In other words, you are right, dropping the table wipes out the `@@rowcount` of the rows inserted. However, there still may be an issue with your query. Even if you remove the drop table statement, `@@rowcount` is only going to return the number of rows impacted by the insert. So -- if you were looking to get the total accumulated `@@rowcount` you will need to come up with a different approach.

Comment: It's possible to capture the value using sp_executesql, but it would be very cumbersome to do.  It would involve calling each of your sections in an sp_executesql all wrapped up in another sp_executesql and passing the rowcount from the `@tempProdSQL` down the line.  It'd be ugly, Yobik is right -- you may want to rethink the design here.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be concerned with performance in this case. The caching of `rowcount` happens anyway so you're not going to save much of anything by trying to shove it all into one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

In the documentation for [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx), there is a "Remarks" section that says this:

> sp_executesql has the same behavior as EXECUTE with regard to batches,
>   the scope of names, and database context. The Transact-SQL statement
>   or batch in the sp_executesql stmt parameter is not compiled until the
>   sp_executesql statement is executed. The contents of stmt are then
>   compiled and executed as an execution plan separate from the execution
>   plan of the batch that called sp_executesql. The sp_executesql batch
>   cannot reference variables declared in the batch that calls
>   sp_executesql. Local cursors or variables in the sp_executesql batch
>   are not visible to the batch that calls sp_executesql. Changes in
>   database context last only to the end of the sp_executesql statement.

Another way of saying this would be that because the dynamic SQL is not compiled until run-time, it is treated as a separate batch and has its own context outside of the procedure building/executing it.

If you take advantage of the additional arguments to `sp_executesql`, being `@params` and `@param1`, you can find the `@@row_count` inside the dynamic SQL statement, and pass that value back to the main batch/context.

**Solution:**

Edit: Moving the `@@rowcount` check immediately after the `@tempProdSQL` piece of the Dynamic SQL.

```
declare @row_cnt int --add this to your procedure's variables

set @completeSQL = @tempProdSQL + ' set @row_cnt_dyn = @@rowcount ' + @deleteSQL + @insertSQL + ' DROP TABLE #tempProd' 

print (@completeSQL)
exec sp_executesql @completeSQL
        , N'@row_cnt_dyn int out' --establishing the param in the dynamic sql batch
        , @row_cnt_dyn = @row_cnt out --this is getting the value out of the dynamic batch into the main batch

set @archiveSize = @row_cnt
```

Comment: And what would it return after `drop table`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin After a `drop table`, the `@@rowcount` would return 0. Your question caused me to realize I had the `@@rowcount` in the wrong spot, according to the OP's question. Moved it to after the `@tempProdSQL`, per the question. This will return the requested number of rows effected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the value of @@rowcount immediately after @tempProdSQL and return it to the outer context using an output parameter:

```
SET @completeSQL = @tempProdSQL + '; SET @archiveSize1 = @@ROWCOUNT; ' + @deleteSQL + @insertSQL + ' DROP TABLE #tempProd'

PRINT(@completeSQL)

EXEC sp_executesql @completeSQL, N'@archiveSize1 INT OUTPUT', @archiveSize1 = @archiveSize OUTPUT

SELECT '@archiveSize:', @archiveSize
```